# Paypal - can i skip billing address & phone number info for credit card payment?

Tags: paypal, credit-card, billing

i'm integrating paypal digital goods payment with my website. When user do a direct payment(buy as guest - pay by credit card), by default,user need to fill up credit card billing address and phone number before going to credit card number, csc fill-up. Is there a way to skip billing address info or is it required by paypal credit card payment? thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191823/is-billing-address-required-for-paypal-direct-payment-credit-card/11195784#11195784

Comment: I ppsted an answer in the linked duplicate question above. Use 'None' for address fields and '0000' for zip and a valid country for the country code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it so they aren't asked for a shipping address, but PayPal will always ask for a billing address and phone number for their own records/information validation.

Answer (score 0):

just set

```
noshipping=1
```

or 2 depending on your needs during api call.