# Is billing address required for Paypal direct payment (credit card)

Tags: paypal, credit-card, billing

when user do a direct payment(buy as guest - pay by credit card), by default,user need to fill up credit card billing address and phone number before going to credit card number, csc etc. Actually i don't really want the billing address, can i direct user to credit card number,csc directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some credit cards require billing address. For example, Visa requires billing address.

Yes, you are required to provide billing address if you want to accept all types of credit card.

Just FYI, you also need to display PayPal Express Button if you use PayPal Direct. Please make sure PayPal approve your merchant account first. They sometimes do not approve your merchant account  depending on your business type.

Good luck!

Comment: I own a VISA card and I dont remember providing my billing address anywhere. This works at least in India. This is NOT related to Paypal, but VISA.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? I'm testing in paypal sandbox, and I'm not required to send the billing address, but I just want to confirm that when going to production I won't have any issue...

Answer (score 1):

Based on my own experience with Paypal's various APIs, you will need to include either billing or shipping information. But for the record, you should refer to their documentation (which is pretty good):

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference

Comment: Hi Bob, i've gone through all the related documents. actually i'm implementing paypal digital goods which contains the direct payment feature. i found sth here:https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoDirectPayment, it said the address field is required. but this is for dodirectpayment, not sure whether it is applicable to credit card in digital goods or not

Answer (score 0):

Many CC forms I have filled in do not ask for a address, but they work. What were they sending for the address? I found that if you did not have an address, you can't send empty strings, that just leads to error, but if you put 'None' in the address fields and '0000' for the zip code, it is accepted. These are the paramaters I send to the call with every CC purchase, and they work every time:

```
self.co_params['street'] = 'None'
self.co_params['city'] = 'None'
self.co_params['state'] = 'None'
self.co_params['zip'] = '0000'
self.co_params['countrycode'] = 'GB'
....
nvp_obj = wpp.doDirectPayment(self.co_params)
```

This is using django-paypal. There are other parameters as well, but this address combination worked for me. I did not find this in Paypal's documentation, but trial and error.